# Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider+HttpTriggerBinding+NullListener' for function

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-http-trigger

I have a HTTP trigger, it is running fine locally. But in the deployed version, recently it stopped running & when calling the endpoint URL via postman I'm getting 404 Not Found error.  No new changes were deployed specifically related to that trigger. In Azure Application Insights, I noticed the below message under traces & don't see any other exceptions related to this trigger.

> Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider+HttpTriggerBinding+NullListener' for function 'FileProcessorTrigger'

Also, the other HTTP triggers are working fine in the deployed version.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your issue. I have noticed the issue because it is coming after deployed in azure. Call the respective azure function with respective authentication process.

#### Workaround

##### Function with authentication level anonymous

I have deployed the azure function using Visual Studio.  The function with **anonymous** authentication. After deployed in azure trying to call the function in portal and postman. I can be able to get the 200 responses without any issues.

##### Function with authentication level has **Function**

[image]

Tried to call the function without function key

[image]

In Application Insights response i got the same issue

[image]

###### After I added the function key Results follows:

[image]

Application Insights response

[image]